# Como dar um Regex antes de uma string? E selecionar?

Tags: c#, string, regex

O que preciso fazer é o seguinte: vamos supor que a string é -> `:`.

No entanto eu quero selecionar *"somente"* a string antes do `:` usando o `Regex`.

Para ficar mais claro:

"**selecionar essa palavra**: outra palavra aqui"

Lembrando que o `:` não deve ser selecionado.

Comment: Tente utilizar isto:   ^(.*?):

Comment: @Fernando Tem como fazer isso antes do -> (:)  ??

Comment: Sim, uma outra alternativa é utilizar Match result = Regex.Match(text, @"^.*?(?=:)");  neste caso o regex irá pegar tudo até o primeiro (:)

Comment: @SérgioHenrique Você sempre pode escolher uma (e apenas uma) resposta correta para as suas perguntas. Você marca uma resposta como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neste caso o REGEX irá pegar tudo até o primeiro (:)

```
Match result = Regex.Match(text, @"^.*?(?=:)");
```

Comment: Excelente! +1 fácil

Comment: Só para adicionar um comentário ao Regex do Fernando. Neste, é utilizado `.*` que corresponde de 0 a ilimitados caracteres lazy `?` e seguido do Positive Lookahead `(?=alguma_string)`, ou seja, irá capturar os caracteres antes da string definida no positive lookahead, exceto terminadores de linha. Caso queira incluir terminadores de linha, use este Regex: `[\s\S]*?(?=:)`

Comment: @danieltakeshi ou adicione a flag `s` (simple line)

Comment: O comentário feito pelo @danieltakeshi deveria ser incorporado na pergunta como explicação da regex. Na minha opinião todas as regexs devem ter explicações pois não só acresce conteúdo à resposta como também ajuda a quem não está dentro do assunto perceber como funciona.

Answer (score 11):

É possível fazer sem *regex* capturando o índice do carácter `:` e depois usando o método `Substring`.

Exemplo:

```
var str = "selecionar esta parte:outra coisa aqui";
var i = str.IndexOf(':');

if(i >= 0)
    str = str.Substring(0, i);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LNK23Y)</sup>

Comment: Vou dar -1 porque não aborda a pergunta usando Regex

Comment: +1 por mostrar uma alternativa a mais do que o AP pediu.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um conceito em `regex` que chama `positive lookahead`, ou seja, olhando pra frente.

```
.*(\w+)(?=:)
```

Procure por um texto que a frente do texto tenha um `:`

<sub>[***Funcionando em regex101***](https://regex101.com/r/7vb4I0/2)</sub>